# Avoid brackets with a command having an optional argument as subscript

Tags: math-mode, macros, subscripts, brackets

I have the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\quot}[3][c]{\frac{#2}{#3#1}}
\begin{document}
\LARGE
$A_\frac{a}{bc}$
$A_{\quot{a}{b}}$
$A_{\quot[d]{a}{b}}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

If I write `$A_\quot{a}{b}$` instead of `$A_{\quot{a}{b}}$`

or `$A_\quot[d]{a}{b}$` instead of `$A_{\quot[d]{a}{b}}$` I get an error.

```
! Missing { inserted.
```

Is it possible to modify my `\quot` command in order to suppress the extra brackets?

Comment: i don't think it's possible in any straightforward way.  `\frac`, with two arguments, gets away with it because it has no optional arguments, and the expansion is "doubly braced" so that acts as a single token when it's read.

Comment: What about `\newcommand{\quot}[3][c]{{\frac{#2}{#3#1}}}`?

Answer (score 5):

`$A_\frac{a}{bc}$` works because `_` does expansion in order to find a left brace, which may also be implicit. Thus the expansion of `\frac` is pursued all the way, since the usual definition is

```
% latex.ltx, line 4260:
\def\frac#1#2{{\begingroup#1\endgroup\over#2}}
```

and so the `{` before `\begingroup` is scanned when the arguments have already been absorbed.

This doesn't happen with `\quot`, because it has an optional argument, so the expansion ends at `\kernel@ifnextchar` because this macro begins with `\let`.

Adding a pair of braces to the definition, like in

```
\newcommand{\quot}[3][c]{{\frac{#2}{#3#1}}}
```

will not solve the issue. You could do it in an indirect way:

```
\newcommand{\quot}{\bgroup\innerquot}
\newcommand{\innerquot}[3][c]{\frac{#2}{#3#1}\egroup}
```

but I recommend getting the habit of using braces around subscripts. If you try

```
$A_\notin$
```

you'll probably understand why. And no, there's no way to make `\notin` work in subscript without braces, that is, one needs to type `$A_{\notin}$`. The trick above works because `\quot` will make an ordinary symbol and the braces do no harm when used in text style.

Comment: Are you sure about your commentary about `$A_\notin$`? I tested it against `$A_{\notin}$`, and the output obtained was exactly the same.

Comment: @MatemáticosChibchas Maybe you're using a math font package where `\notin` is mapped to a single charatcter.

Comment: You are right, I am using `txfonts`. Oh my, I am willing to follow your advise about using braces, for the sake of coherence... but I love code parsimony too much!!!